# return all the variables at once

Tags: python, regex, pandas

hey i am working on data validation and want to compare multiple regex conditions variable if all satisfies my current codes goes like this

```
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.files['file'])
        f = request.files['file']
        data_xls = pd.read_excel(f)
        df2 = data_xls.reset_index()
        name_filter = df2[df2['Pensioner Name'].str.match('^[a-zA-Z\s\.]*$')]
        cnic_filter = df2[df2['CNIC'].str.match('^[\'][0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}[\']$')]
        wallet_filter = df2[df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str).str.contains('^[0-9+]{8}$')]
        mobile_filter = df2[df2['Mobile Number'].astype(str).str.contains('^[3+][0-9+]{9}$')]
     return name_filter.to_html()
```

how can i return all the variables at once validating all the regex now its only returning name_filter

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not validating one result but all results and filtering them out.

So assuming that you want all the results to pass and be true and the case where they are all true.

```
# COMPARE IF THE SAME DATASETS ARE PRESENT, EVEN AFTER PASSING ALL THE CONDITIONS AS TRUE
if df2[df2['Pensioner Name'].str.match('^[a-zA-Z\s\.]*$'].equals(df2['Pensioner Name'])     and df2[df2['CNIC'].str.match('^[\'][0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}[\']$'].equals(df2['CNIC'])     and df[df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str).str.contains('^[0-9+]{8}$'].equals(df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str)) and  df2[df2['Mobile Number'].astype(str).contains('^[3+][0-9+]{9}$')].equals(df2[['Mobile Number'].astype(str)):
    return df2.to_html()
else:
    return '''<h2> Error in data </h2>'''
```

Comment: Thanks @High-Octane for answering but i am getting an error like this now TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'

Comment: Can you share a sample set of dummy data for me to check?

Comment: Pensioner Name CNIC  Claim No Wallet Account No MobileNumber
CHANESER 41207-0800205-9' 'BDS00229' 25358000 3203501312

Comment: it is something like this please ignore the claim no for now

Comment: Can you convert all your columns as below?

df2['Pensioner Name'] = df2['Pensioner Name'].astype(str)

And then try the other code again?

Comment: although  i tried something which partially work check in the code i am editing

Comment: I guess there is no other way than to use the individual code. Compare, I'll edit it shortly and post in the same answer

Comment: Edited, please try the answer in the edited region.

Comment: if df2[df2['Pensioner Name'].str.match('^[a-zA-Z\s\.]*$'].equals(df2['Pensioner Name']) and df2[df2['CNIC'].str.match('^[\'][0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}[\']$'].equals(df2['CNIC'])and df[df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str).str.contains('^[0-9+]{8}$'].equals(df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str)) and  df2[df2['Mobile Number'].astype(str).contains('^[3+][0-9+]{9}$')].equals(df2[['Mobile Number'].astype(str)):
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works for me. Although the condition was not satisfied. It still works.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Pensioner Name' : ['CHANESER','CHANESERS'],
     'CNIC' : ['41207-0800205-9','41207-0800205-9'],
     'Wallet Account No' : ['BDS00229','BDS00229'],
     'MobileNumber' : ['3203501312','3203501312']
     }
)



if df2[df2['Pensioner Name'].str.match('^[a-zA-Z\s\.]*$')].equals(df2['Pensioner Name']) and \
df2[df2['CNIC'].str.match('^[\'][0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}[\']$')].equals(df2['CNIC'])and \
df2[df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str).str.contains('^[0-9+]{8}$')].equals(df2['Wallet Account No'].astype(str)) and \
df2[df2['Mobile Number'].astype(str).contains('^[3+][0-9+]{9}$')].equals(df2['Mobile Number'].astype(str)):
    print("works!")
else:
    print("not works!")
```